# jTDS connection string: connect to a MS SQL Server instance with a backslash

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am using the jTDS driver in a Java application. The database administrator told me that the SQL Server instance name is

`MSSQL-DB09v1\v1`

How should I write the connection URL?

I have been using something like

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-name/database_name
```

for some time and it works well, but don't know the right connection string when the instance name contains a backslash.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Did further research and tests. Found out the correct connection URL string in this case is:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-name/database_name;instance=instance_name
```

In my case, the connection string is:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server-name/MSSQL-DB09v1;instance=v1
```

See [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) [FAQs](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) for more details

Comment: i did, thanks. in my case the hostname was like this MSSQL-DB09v1\v1, backslash. Escaping that in java didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar case where my DBA gave me a database on a server with the following connection: `{SERVER_NAME}\{INSTANCE}`.  That syntax worked when connecting to the server and instance using SSMS, but it didn't work when connecting through the Java driver.

Instead, the following syntax worked for me:

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://{SERVER_NAME};databaseName={DATABASE_NAME);instance={INSTANCE}`

Notice that I had to move the instance to a connection string parameter.  Once I did this, everything worked well.

For reference, see [this specific JTDS FAQ](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#instanceName).

Answer (score 0):

-Your database would be running on a "dbo" schema.

-So you need to make sure you establish a connection to felicitate querying in a way the dbo schema handles your query.(While you are using getConnection() function)

-You can do that by adding name of your database in front of the server name in the connection string. like below

`ConnectionUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**yourservername:1433/yourdatabase**;database=yourdatabse;user=username;password=password;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";`

instead of

`ConnectionUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**yourservername:1433**;database=yourdatabse;user=username;password=password;encrypt=false;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";`